# Redirecting all request to a specific folder, works except for SSL doesn't?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder on my server called john. Inside this folder is an application I am working on.

I have a self signed cert installed.

if I go to **https://mydomain.com/john/signin** it works.

I have an **.htaccess** that redirects all request that don't begin with either the words *john* or *julian* to **/john**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(john|julian).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ john/$1 [L]
```

Now if I go to a non SSL page like **http://mydomain.com/about** the page **http://mydomain.com/john/about** is loaded (the URL is not redirected).

However if I go to an ssl page like **https://mydomain.com/signin** I get a "**404 Not found**" error.

Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was. I needed to change `AllowOverride` from `none` to `All` in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` file.